# How to get a better quality diagonal line from Flash to YouTube?

Tags: youtube, animation-rendering, flash

I'm working on a video incorporating Flash animation into Premiere Pro to then upload to YouTube. When I upload it to YouTube however the diagonal lines are terribly distorted:

Youtube:

[image: laser on youtube]

Flash:

[image: laser on flash]

What should I be checking for either in Flash or Premiere to ensure those lines are crisp when published on YouTube?

Comment: What you're probably seeing there is an artefact of chroma subsampling. Youtube videos are usually compressed as h.264 with 4:2:0 subsampling. What this means is that colour is sampled at a quarter of the resolution of brightness. A workaround would be to use a less saturated red.

Comment: @stib using HSL in Flash I lowered Saturation to 80% on the red, it helped a decent amount. Might try lowering it a bit more to find a sweet spot. If you want to leave that as an answer then I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Lowering it to 60% while not as vibrant as I might like completely fixes the distortion. Thanks!